# Is it possible that two measurements will determine if the labels are right?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, combinations

Suppose we have $6$ identically looking cubes that weigh  $1,\dots,6$ grams, respectively. Someone has labeled them 1g, 2g, 3g, 4g, 5g,6g however he might have labeled them incorrectly.

Suppose you have a scale and you can't feel the weight by your hand, is it possible to **use the scale twice** to tell if the labels are correct?

### Edit

The scale can only tell you if two side are equal, or that which side is heavier. The answer by @Evan means that we are allow to measure the weight of the set of cubes. Sorry for the confusion I've made.

Comment: @EvanAad Fine, thank you very much.

Comment: I've now added an informal explanation too.

Comment: @EvanAad I'll look into it.

Comment: Question is very interesting, thank you, I can not work but think about it :)
To avoid possible future misunderstandings please confirm that scales can tell if two sides are equal or which side is heavier (so there are 3 possible outcomes, not just if they are equal - that would be 2 possible outcomes)

Comment: @lesnik sure, three possibilities. You can either tell if it is equal, or left is heavier or lighter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Compare (6) and (1,2,3). If scales are not equal we know some labels are wrong. If they are equal, we know 6 is 6, set {1,2,3} really contains cubes with weights {1,2,3} (may be wrong labelled), set {4,5} really contains cubes weighted 4 and 5.
2. Compare (6, 1) and (5, 3). This time we expect right side to be heavier. !!!

Left side weights at least 7 (because we know real 6 in on the left). And the right side can weight 8 only if it has heaviest from sets {1,2,3} and {4, 5}, that is 5 and 3.

Comment: No flaw in your answer, you are gorgeous.

Answer (score 2):

THIS ANSWER WAS WRITTEN UNDER THE IMPRESSION THAT OP MEANT A SCALE LIKE THIS:
[image]
RATHER THAN A SCALE LIKE THIS:
[image: ![enter image description here]. AFTER THE ANSWER WAS WRITTEN, OP ADDED THE CLARIFICATION THAT IT WAS MEANT THE OTHER WAY ROUND.

---

No, it is not possible to determine whether the labels are correct.

Contrary to what might appear at first sight, **the proof is short; it is contained in the last paragraph preceding the concluding section, *Generalizations*.** The rest of this post is dedicated to formalizing what needs be proved (the resulting formalization being the highlighted sentence near the end of this post), to introducing notation used in the formalization and in the proof, and to arguing that the formalization agrees with the problem that is described informally in [the Original Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1981491/37058).

Denote the set of labels by $L$, i.e. $L := \{1, 2, \dots, 6\}$. Denote by $\Pi$ the set consisting of all the ways to label the cubes. For every $\pi \in \Pi$, and for every $\ell \in L$, $\pi(\ell)$ is the weight of the cube labeled $\ell$ as per the labeling schema $\pi$. In other words, $\Pi$ is the set of permutations of $L$. Denote the identity permutation by $I$, and denote the given labeling schema by $\pi^*$.

For every labeling schema $\pi \in \Pi$, denote by $w_\pi$ the function that assigns to every subset, $S \subseteq L$, of cubes, identified by their labels, their weight per $\pi$:
$$
w_\pi(S) := \sum_{s \in S} \pi(s).
$$

Every subset of labels, $S \subseteq L$, induces an equivalence relation, $\cong_S$, on $\Pi$ as follows. For every $\pi_1, \pi_2 \in \Pi$, $\pi_1 \cong_S \pi_2$ iff $w_{\pi_1}(S) = w_{\pi_2}(S)$. (Verify that this is indeed an equivalence relation!) Denote by $E_S$ the family of equivalence classes corresponding to $\cong_S$. For every labeling schema, $\pi \in \Pi$, $\pi$'s equivalence class in $E_S$ shall be denoted by $[\pi]_S$.

With this terminology, we will show that the problem reduces to the following question. Is there some pair $S_1, S_2 \subseteq L$, such that
$$
[I]_{S_1} \cap [I]_{S_2} = \{I\}\tag{1}\label{Apple}
$$

To see that this formulation indeed captures the problem statement described in the Original Post, suppose firstly that there are some $S_1,S_2 \subseteq L$ such that \eqref{Apple} holds. Use the scale to weigh the cubes, whose label set $S_1$ is, and then use the scale once more to weigh the cubes, whose label set $S_2$ is. Denote the two weights thus obtained by $w_1, w_2$, respectively. If
$$
w_1 = w_I(S_1)\ \wedge\ w_2 = w_I(S_2), \tag{2}\label{Banana}
$$
report that $\pi^* = I$; otherwise, report that $\pi^* \neq I$. To verify the correctness of this algorithm, it suffices to observe that condition \eqref{Banana} holds iff $\pi^* \in [I]_{S_1}\cap[I]_{S_2}$.

Conversely, suppose there is some pair $S_1,S_2\subseteq L$ of sets of cubes (given by their labels as per the labeling schema $\pi^*$), for which it is possible, by consecutively weighing $S_1$ and $S_2$, to tell whether $\pi^* = I$ or $\pi^* \neq I$. Any algorithm, $\mathfrak{A} = \mathfrak{A}_{S_1, S_2}$, that can be used to reach this determination, can have only indirect access to $\pi^*$ in the form of $S_1$'s and $S_2$'s weights. For every $\pi\in\Pi$, $\mathfrak{A}$ takes $w_\pi(S_1)$, and $w_\pi(S_2)$ as input arguments, and it is based solely on these arguments (as well as on $S_1$ and $S_2$) that $\mathfrak{A}$ must calculate its output: 
$$
\mathfrak{A}\big(w_\pi(S_1), w_\pi(S_2)\big) = \begin{cases}
\mathrm{TRUE} &, \pi = I, \\
\mathrm{FALSE} &, \mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
To see that \eqref{Apple} holds, let $\pi \in [I]_{S_1}\cap[I]_{S_2}$. Then $\mathfrak{A}\big(w_\pi(S_1), w_\pi(S_2)\big) = \mathfrak{A}\big(w_I(S_1), w_I(S_2)\big) = \mathrm{TRUE}$, so that $\pi = I$.

For every distinct pair of labels, $a, b \in L$, denote by $\tau_{\{a,b\}}$ the transposition $(a\ b)$, i.e. $\tau_{\{a, b\}}$ is the permutation $\pi \in \Pi$ that satisfies
$$
\begin{align}
\pi(a) &= b, \\
\pi(b) &= a,
\end{align}
$$
and $\pi(\ell) = \ell$ for every $\ell \in L\setminus\{a,b\}$.

We can now finally show that there are no $S_1, S_2 \subseteq L$, such that \eqref{Apple} holds. Equivalently, we will show the following.

> The set $T$, consisting of all the pairs $(S_1, S_2) \in (\mathcal{P}L)^2$ for which \eqref{Apple} holds, is empty.

Suppose to the contrary, and let $(S_1, S_2) \in T$. Define
$$
S_1' := \begin{cases}
S_1 &, |S_1| \geq 3, \\
L\setminus S_1 &, \mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $|S_1'| \geq 3$, and $(S_1', S_2) \in T$. (Verify!) Choose $B \subseteq L$ as follows. If $|S_1' \cap S_2| \geq 2$, let $B \subseteq S_1'\cap S_2$ be any subset of cardinality $2$. Otherwise, let $B \subseteq S_1' \setminus S_2$ be any subset of cardinality $2$. Then $\tau_B \in [I]_{S_1'} \cap [I]_{S_2}$, so that $\tau_B = I$, a contradiction!

---

***Generalizations***

The proof can be readily adjusted to account for an initial set of $n \geq 5$ cubes equipped with an arbitrary $n$-tuple, $(r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n)$, of distinct real numbers representing the cubes' "weights" (if the "weights" are not distinct, then it is trivially impossible to tell whether the labeling is correct by merely weighing the cubes).

Comment: I want to mention that inequalities can also be used. Your proof, though I haven't carefully read, seems only use the equality condition.

Comment: However, it is very interesting and useful if you've proofed that using equalities only can't accomplish this job, people will not spend time on these possibilities.

Comment: @fizis: My answer solves your question completely. It encompasses all forms of comparison, including, but not restricted to, equalities and inequalities, as long as the conditions stipulated in the question are met, namely that we may not distinguish between the cubes in any way except by obtaining two consecutive measurements of any two subsets of the cubes.

Comment: @fizis: I will try to add a less formal, easier-to-understand explanation of the proof, but it will take me some time.

Comment: While I can't understand your proof right now, I may still raise an additional concern, does your proof use the condition that we have six cubes? What if we have five or four cubes, will your proof also make it impossible?

Comment: @fizis: The proof works for sets of six or more cubes (if there are $n > 6$ cubes, just replace $N$ with the set $N:=\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$). If there are less than six cubes, it *is* possible to determine whether they are labeled correctly using only two measurements.

Comment: That's great. No contradiction with the knowledge I have...

Comment: @fizis: I'd appreciate it if you either accept my answer, or else explain why you do not accept it, so I may correct or clarify it. Thanks.

Comment: I'll accept it if I understand it, sorry for my stupidness. It may take me some time to fully understand it. Please have patience, I'll comment on it if I am not clear at some particular steps.

Comment: @fizis: I did not intend to imply that you're stupid in any way. I have a bad history with users who do not acknowledge my hard work in answering their question by the simple courtesy of accepting the answer. Please feel free to ask any question. I will also try to think of ways to make the informal explanation even clearer.

Comment: You will be rewarded if you are correct, I also like to make my question complete if there is real good answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47312/discussion-between-fizis-and-evan-aad).

Comment: The answer has been up for all of five hours. What's the rush? There's no need to accept it until OP is good and ready. Maybe someone will come up with a proof OP finds more accessible, if OP waits a while. I agree that people should acknowledge hard work, but I'd counsel patience.

Comment: @fizis: I now realize that my proof works almost verbatim with a set of $5$ weights or more, contrary to what I wrote in one of the comments above that it only works with a set of $6$ weights or more but not with less than $6$. Not that it matters now...

Comment: I think you are right about five, because in your case, you are **literally only using the scale(second type) the equality condition.** In that case, I've proved that there is always another permutation let the scale balance in both measurements.

Comment: When you do a lot of editing, it's better to use the [sandbox on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) than to bump a lot on main.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You're right. I'm sorry. It's just that I don't intend to do a lot of editing. I always think that I'm done and that this is the final edit...

Answer (score 1):

Weigh the 2, 3, 5 against the 4, 6. If it doesn't balance, then you know there's an incorrect label. If it does balance, then either the labels are correct, or you're weighing 1, 2, 6 against 4, 5, or you're weighing 1, 3, 4 against 2, 6. Now weigh the 1, 2, 3 against the 6. This can't balance in the other two cases, only in the labels-correct case, and you're done.

Comment: exchange 2,3 fault your answer

Comment: Oops – so close.

Comment: may be inequalities will do the job, keep trying if you have time.